# Calling Q Promise on the basis of conditional logic

Tags: node.js, promise, q

Below is my condition

```
if abc is true
    call async func1, func2
else
    call async func1

function test(): Q.Promise<boolean> {
    if(abc)
       Q.all([func1,func2])
    else
       Q.all([func1])
    //if failed throw reject reason all the way in the chain
}
```

1. As shown, it can be done using `if` and `else` clause, is there a better way to call promise conditionally?
2. How to throw back `error from any one of the promises`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put promises in array and append new one depending on condition:

```
function test(): Q.Promise<Boolean[]> {
    const promises = [func1()] 
    if (abc) promises.push(func2()) 
    return Q.all(promises)
}
```

I corrected type signature a little, because `Q.all` resolves with *array* of values (Boolean in your case) from each underlying promises. You also need to call `func1` and `func2`. And finally, don't forget to return from `test` function.

Comment: what happens if one of the `promise` is `rejected` and how would I throw that `error` all the way up. I am trying to learn `Q.promises`, so excuse me if it's silly question :)

Comment: You don't need to throw explicitly. If one of functions throws or returns rejected promise, then `Q.all` will also reject for you and the error will automatically bubble to Q.all error handler: `test().then(function() {  console.log('all fine') }).catch(function(error) { console.log('something went wrong') })`.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually pretty close already:

```
function test() {
    if(abc)
       return Q.all([func1(),func2()])
    else
       return func1();
}
test().then(() => {
    // do whatever
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Make sure you always return the promises as they don't get chained otherwise.